# Issue with UITableView in ios- Overlapping of previous view even is removed from superview

Tags: iphone, ios

i have two view controllers and i am using sqlite in my project. in one controller i am creating and showing UITableview and i another i am deleting the table cell via sqlite. my problem is while doing deleting operation from one controller and returning to other, the table view gets overlapped with previous old view. i even removed the tableview and re created it. problem doesnt resolves. any help is appreciated.
i attached the screenshot.
[image]

```
// create cell
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;
{
    NSString *cellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    MOProfileTablViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:nil];

    if(cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[MOProfileTablViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];

        cell.profileLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

        [cell.profileLabel setFont: [UIFont fontWithName:kfontNameBold size:18]];

        cell.profileNumberLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

        [cell.profileNumberLabel setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:kFontName size:14]];

    }

    if(selectedIndex == [indexPath row] && [[sqlExecutObj.result objectAtIndex:1] count] > [indexPath row])
    {
        self.preSelectedProfileViewCell = cell;

        cell.selectionButton.hidden = NO;

    }
    else
        cell.selectionButton.hidden = YES;

    if ([[sqlExecutObj.result objectAtIndex:1] count] && [[sqlExecutObj.result objectAtIndex:1] count] > [indexPath row])
    {//set cell background color
        cell.backgroundView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:[profileColorArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]]];

        cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    }
    else
    {
        if ([[sqlExecutObj.result objectAtIndex:1] count]== [indexPath row]) {



        }else {
        cell.backgroundView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"add_newprofile.png"]];

        cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        }
    }

    if ([[sqlExecutObj.result objectAtIndex:1] count] && [[sqlExecutObj.result objectAtIndex:1] count] > [indexPath row])
    {
        cell.profileLabel.text = [[sqlExecutObj.result objectAtIndex:0] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

        cell.profileNumberLabel.text = [[sqlExecutObj.result objectAtIndex:3] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]; //settings-icon.png

        if ([[[sqlExecutObj.result objectAtIndex:1] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] isEqualToString:@"default"])
        {
            [cell.profileImage.layer setBorderWidth:0.0f];
            cell.profileImage.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"group.png"] ;

            cell.profileImage.frame = CGRectMake(cell.selectionButton.frame.origin.x+cell.selectionButton.frame.size.width+15,13,30 ,30);
        }
        else
        {
            [cell.profileImage.layer setBorderWidth:2.0f];

            cell.profileImage.frame = CGRectMake(cell.selectionButton.frame.origin.x+cell.selectionButton.frame.size.width+15,10,30 , 30);

            UIImage *imge=[UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:[[sqlExecutObj.result objectAtIndex:1]objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]]];

            cell.profileImage.image = imge;
        }
        if ( [ [ [sqlExecutObj.result objectAtIndex:0] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] isEqualToString:@"PENDING..."] || [ [ [sqlExecutObj.result objectAtIndex:0] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] isEqualToString:@"New Virtual Number"] ) {

            cell.accessoryType =UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
            cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
             [cell.profileLabel setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:kFontName size:16.5]];

        } else {
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDetailDisclosureButton;
        cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleGray;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
        cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
         if ([[sqlExecutObj.result objectAtIndex:1] count] == [indexPath row]) {
             //customizing cell for manage account
        cell.profileLabel.text = @"Manage Account";
        cell.profileLabel.frame = CGRectMake(cell.profileImage.frame.origin.x+cell.profileImage.frame.size.width+10,12,150,24);
        cell.backgroundView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"settings-bg.png"]];   //settings-icon.png
        cell.profileNumberLabel.text = nil;
        [cell.profileImage.layer setBorderWidth:0.0f];
        cell.profileImage.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"settings-icon.png"] ;
        cell.profileImage.frame = CGRectMake(cell.selectionButton.frame.origin.x+cell.selectionButton.frame.size.width+15,10,30 ,30);
        [cell.profileLabel setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:kFontName size:18]];
        cell.profileLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
         }
         else
         {
             //customizing cell for add-new-profile cell
        cell.profileLabel.text = nil;
        cell.profileNumberLabel.text = nil;
        cell.profileImage.image = nil;
        [cell.profileLabel setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:kFontName size:20]];
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
        cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;


         }
    }

    return cell;

}
```

Comment: Screenshot is not enough to solve this. You need to provide the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` for both your tables, and also show what reuse identifier you are using for each of them.

Comment: actually, no problem with creating tableview, i am saying this because from other viw controllers i am doing the same operation, its working properly.

Comment: please find my attached code above.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are not using the `cellIdentifier` identifier correctly: when you define the cell, you pass the identifier in the constructor, but when you try dequeueing the cell, you pass `nil`:

```
MOProfileTablViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:nil];
//                                                                        ^^^^
//                                                                        HERE
```

Documentation specifically calls for that parameter not to be `nil`:

> `identifier`
>
> - A string identifying the cell object to be reused. This parameter must not be `nil`.

In general, your method looks "to busy": if you need to configure cells differently under different circumstances, consider using different reuse identifiers for cells with different look. This wold help preventing situations like this, and also help you improve the frame rate when scrolling the table.